# What is the best way to find all possible scrabble words using scala?

Tags: scala

What is the best way to find all possible scrabble words using scala?

There is a dictionary of possible words and letters that can be used to combine those words.
For example there is a dictionary `["lobby", "bar", "bold", "bobby"]` and letters `"borblyd"`. The result should be `["lobby", "bold"]`.

Comment: Adding as a comment to offer a (very inefficient) baseline solution: `def words(letters: String, dictionary: Set[String]): Seq[String] = (1 to letters.length).flatMap(letters.combinations(_)).flatMap(_.permutations).filter(dictionary)`. Please note however that `bold` is not part of the valid solution (perhaps a typo?)

Comment: @stefanobaghino you're right about `bold`, that was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a list of all possible letter combinations. Then filter out the real words. Definitely use an `Iterator` to prevent blowing up your computer. Because of the Iterators it's not a *pure* functional solution, since they have mutable state, but it will be fairly efficient.

```
val letters = "borbly"
val dictionary = Set("lobby", "bar", "bold", "bobby")
val possibilities = Iterator.range(1, letters.length + 1).flatMap(letters.combinations).flatMap(_.permutations)
possibilities.filter(dictionary).toList
```

Alternatively you can do it the other way around, which looks less cool but might be a lot faster if you have a lot of letters:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

@tailrec
def canBeMade(word: String, letters: String): Boolean =
  word.isEmpty || (letters.contains(word.head) && canBeMade(word.tail, letters.replaceFirst(word.head.toString, "")))

dictionary.filter(canBeMade(_, letters))
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is typo as @stefanobaghino menthoned: "bold" should not be in the result. My idea is to build the map Char -> Occurs for each word and for input letters and use those maps to find scramble words:

```
def chars2Occurs(chars: Seq[Char]): Map[Char, Int] = {
  chars.foldLeft(Map.empty[Char, Int]) {
    case (map, ch) =>
      val occurs = map.get(ch).getOrElse(0) + 1
      map + ((ch -> occurs))
  }
}
def getScrambleWords(words: Seq[String], letters: Array[Char]): Seq[String] = {
  val etalon: Map[Char, Int] = chars2Occurs(letters)
  val word2Occur: Seq[(String, Map[Char, Int])] = words.map { word =>
    (word, chars2Occurs(word))
  }
  val result: Seq[String] = word2Occur.flatMap { case (word, map) =>
    val isOk = map.forall { case (c, n) =>
      etalon.get(c) match {
        case Some(k) => k >= n
        case None => false
      }
    }
    if (isOk) Some(word) else None
  }
  result
}
```

Comment: You are right about `"bold"`. I've fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach – Go over each word in the dictionary and keep it only if: 1) the word is not longer than the count of letters in hand, and, 2) the count of remained letters after removing every character in the word from the letters in hand equals the original letter count minus the word length:

```
val letters = "borblyd".toSeq
val letterCount = letters.size

val dict = Set("lobby", "bar", "bold", "bobby")

dict.filter( word => 
  word.length <= letterCount &&
  word.foldLeft(letters)(
    (lettersRemained, ch) => lettersRemained.diff(Seq(ch))
  ).size == letterCount - word.length
)
// res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(lobby, bold)
```